# how do I hide the domain name from an email?

Tags: networking, centos7, postfix-mta, dovecot, squirrelmail

I have created a mail server using postfix, dovecot and squirrelmail in centos7.

```
 For example if the email is abcd@something.com. How to hide @Something.com and show only abcd in the receiver's inbox?
```

Comment: Doing something like that often will cause the e-mail to end up in the junk box, or it can get your server blacklisted by legitimate e-mail servers. In any case, you should ask on [sf] for a business network because it is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

Although not really a programming question, the solution is that the "From" header in the email has to have a display name part such as:

`From: "My Name" <abcd@example.com>`

Then the "My Name" part will show in most email clients upon arrival. In SquirrelMail (and most other email clients), the way you make sure this happens it to go to the personal information options and make sure you have something filled in the full name field.